# .Net MAUI installaion issue

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, sdk, maui

[image]I am completely new to .Net and I was installing the .Net sdk for .Net maui , I was following the following documentation -
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/net-maui-on-linux-with-visual-studio-code/ba-p/3982195

The installation was successful , I ran the dotnet command [image]

but i am getting this weird error , I am not able to figure it out , help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you set the path correctly after installation?